# Checking a python string for escaped characters

Tags: python, html, string, html-escape-characters

I'm trying to check if a string in python contains escaped characters. The simplest way to do this is to set a list of escaped characters, then check if any element in the list is in the string:

```
s = "A &amp; B"
escaped_chars = ["&amp;",
     "&quot;",
     "&apos;",
     "&gt;"]

for char in escaped_chars:
    if char in s:
        print "escape char '{0}' found in string '{1}'".format(char, s)
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why are you asking for a better way? What's wrong with your current method? Ugly? Bad performance? Please ask specific questions

Comment: Because there are many other escaped_chars which I have not included, such as `&lt;`, etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) (See also [`re` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)):

```
>>> s = "A &amp; B"
>>> import re
>>> matched = re.search(r'&\w+;', s)
>>> if matched:
...     print "escape char '{0}' found in string '{1}'".format(matched.group(), s)
... 
escape char '&amp;' found in string 'A &amp; B'
```

- `&`, `;` matches `&`, `;` literally.
- `\w` matches word character (alphabet, digits, `_`).
- `\w+` matches one or more word characters.